# Script Bundling in WebForms with Virtual Directories

Tags: vb.net, webforms, virtual-directory, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

We have a separate "Framework" project for shared controls, javascript, etc. that is used by this and other projects.  The Framework project is included in our solution, and we made a virtual directory for it with IIS so we can still make relative links to files with `~/Framework`.

So, we want to begin using the new Web Optimization bundles for scripts and styles.  Everything is working fine, but we are having issues when attempting to use bundling with JS files in the virtual directory.  When `debug="false"` is set, the files are correctly bundled & minified.  When `debug="true"` is set it does not include *any* of the files!

Clearly it has access to the files since it can bundle & minify them together. Is there a way to make this work?

---

Here's what I have in `App_Start/BundleConfig.vb`

```
    Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(bundles As BundleCollection)
        Dim mainBundle = New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/main")
        mainBundle.Orderer = New AsIsBundleOrderer()
        mainBundle.Include("~/Framework/Javascript/Main/Library.jQuery.js")
        mainBundle.Include("~/Framework/Javascript/Main/Library.jQuery.ui.js")
        'snip....
        mainBundle.Include("~/Framework/Javascript/Main/CP.Base.js")

        bundles.Add(mainBundle)
    End Sub
```

Here's what I have in my MasterPage:

```
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main") %>
```

Comment: what version of optimization are you using? 1.1?

Comment: Doh! I was on 1.0 and an update to 1.1 fixed this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create a class under *App_Code* folder in your project and add this code in to the class

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(bundles As BundleCollection)
    Dim mainBundle = New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/main")
    mainBundle.Orderer = New DefaultBundleOrderer()
    mainBundle.Include("~/HTML5Components/adc.js")
    bundles.Add(mainBundle)
End Sub
```

after that open *Global.asax*

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)         
End Sub
```